# cakephp registration and login form

Tags: php, cakephp, user-registration, cakephp-model

I'm doing registration and login form using cakephp. I'm new to cakephp framework. I have downloaded and installed cakephp on my system. And I've already connected into my database table. I've made few changes in `core.php` and `database.php`.

I'm following these tutorials to do registration and login form.

http://alvinalexander.com/php/cakephp-user-registration-form-example-recipe

http://www.grasphub.com/2013/01/simplest-registration-form-in-cakephp/

http://karven.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/create-simple-user-authentication-using-cakephp-auth-component/

I've tried everthing. But none of them does not works. I don't know where i need to create these php files. I'm new to MVC design pattern too... Here anyone give me some step by step procedure to finish this simple task.. I'm not ask any coding here.. I want some step by step procedure..

Comment: You seem to have read a lot of blog posts, did you also read the official documentation along with its http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html ? Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark : I've read that too. But still didn't get it. Version 2.4.6.  First step: what can i do?

Comment: "I've tried everthing. But none of them does not works." - What errors are you getting? Which step from those blogs actually failed?

Comment: @jimmymadon : Now i got registration form view. I will try to do it

Answer (score 3):

It may look a bit hard, but when you understand its scheme it becomes super simple:

- The model layer handles everything about data. It will silently connect to the database configuration declared in the variable "useDbConfig" in the model (if not declared, it will connect to `default` config). They are stored in the `Models` folder. "Handles everything about data" means that it fetches the data from a datasource, validates data that will be saved, formats data, etc.

  Models can attach a `behavior`. Think of it as an "interface" in OOP terms (not the same, but somewhat close). They provide common functionality between them (for example, `TranslateBehavior` makes data for that model translatable). They are stored in the `Models/Behavior` folder. You can call them in the array variable `$actsAs`, or load it on the fly. For example:

  ```
  public $actsAs = array('Translate');
  ```
- The controller layer handles all actions that will be done with the data. It will silently instance the model with the same name as the controller to handle the data, but you can tell a controller to instance many different models to suit your needs. They are stored in the `Controllers` folder. Usually functions in controllers are called `actions`, because when a HTTP request is handled in your server, it will be delegated to the corresponding function in your controller. Say, http://www.example.com/users/login will call your action `login()` inside `UsersController`.

  Controllers can attach a `component`. It's the same as a `behavior`, but specifically for controllers. They are stored in `Controllers/Components` folder. For example, `PaginationComponent` makes the data fetched in a controller paginable, so you can sort it, divide it by pages, etc. You can call it in the variable `$components`, or load it on the fly. For example:

  ```
  public $components = array('Paginate');
  ```
- The view layer handles all your presentation. It means that they have all the HTML + Javascript that the user will see. It's called from a controller after an action is resolved. It silently will render the view inside `View/ControllerName/action.ctp`, It means that, for example, when `login()` action has finished, it will then render the view `View/Users/login.ctp`. Views usually use the layout `default` to render, but you can change it in the variable `$layout` inside the controller. You can pass variables from controllers to view through the function `$set()` in the controller.

  Views can use `helpers`; they are the same as components and behaviors, but for the views. But you have to declare them in the **controller** in the variable `$helpers`. They are stored in the `Views/Helpers` folder. For example, the default `HtmlHelper` lets you make some tags easier, like `<img>`, `<a>`, `<script>` or `<link>` for css.

  Also views can use elements. They are kind of blocks that you can reuse in any view or layout you want. You just create an element in `Views/Elements` folder, and use them with `$this->element('nameOfTheElement');`.

In summary, you for the login you will need an `User.php` model, an `UsersController.php` controller, and a `login.ctp` view. In the controller you will need the `AuthComponent` to load, because it will handle the login. In the view you probably will need the `HtmlHelper` and `FormHelper`, but they are loaded by default. And in the `login()` function in the controller, you just check if `Auth->login()` succeeds or not, and take the proper actions.

Once you're more experienced, you can look at the convention called `fat models, skinny controllers` to be more organized.

Good luck!

Comment: I have put view.ctp in my View Folder. view.ctp is a registration form. Now i can see a registration form without an error. Then where can i do database query? user.php in Model Folder?

Comment: You can call your query in your `view()` function in `UsersController` through the model, like `$this->User->find/save` (depending of your action)